# Strange foreign key behavior on empty tables in SQLite 3

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have SQLite 3 with the following setup (simplified):

```
create table Location(LocationId integer not null,
                      LocationCode text not null, 
                      primary key(LocationId),
                      unique(LocationCode));
```

The table above is being referenced by Department:

```
create table Department(DepartmentId integer not null,
                        LocationId integer not null,
                        DepartmentCode text not null,
                        primary key(LocationId, DepartmentCode),
                        foreign key(LocationId) references Location(LocationId));
```

The table above is being referenced by Child:

```
create table Event(EventId integer not null,
                   LocationId integer not null,
                   unique(LocationId, EventDate),
                   primary key(eventId),
                   foreign key(LocationId) references Location(LocationId));
```

The table above references table Location:

```
create table Parent(ParentId integer not null,
                    EmailAddress text not null,
                    primary key(ParentId),
                    unique(EmailAddress));
```

The table above is being referenced by table Child:

```
create table Child(ChildId integer not null,
                   ParentId integer not null,
                   ChildCode text not null,
                   DepartmentId integer not null,
                   primary key(ChildId, ParentId),
                   foreign key(ParentId) references Parent(ParentId),
                   foreign key(DepartmentId) references Department(DepartmentId));
```

The table child is the one I'm trying to delete from.

At this point, the whole database is empty, and has "pragma foreign_keys=ON".

While testing a script to clear the database I encountered an error while deleting from the empty table `Child` having a foreign key to the (also empty) table `Parent`.

When I issue the command `delete from child` (while is already empty), SQLite3 comes back with the error message "foreign keys mismatch".

This is the vital part of the delete script:

```
delete from Child;
delete from Parent;
delete from Event;
delete from Department;
delete from Location;
```

I saw some posts here about temporarily disabling foreign key support, but that does not make sense to me. 
That makes the whole process of implementing a foreign key relationship unnecessary.

Comment: Your department table has the PK `(LocationId, DepartmentCode)`, but your foreign key references `DepartmentId` (which is something a more strict DBMS would't let you create in the first place)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation (hidden in the source code) says:

> A foreign key constraint requires that the key columns in the parent
>   table are collectively subject to a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint.
>   […]
>   If the required index cannot be found, either because:
>
> 1. The named parent key columns do not exist, or
> 2. The named parent key columns do exist, but are not subject to a
>      UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint, or
> 3. No parent key columns were provided explicitly as part of the
>      foreign key definition, and the parent table does not have a
>      PRIMARY KEY, or
> 4. No parent key columns were provided explicitly as part of the
>      foreign key definition, and the PRIMARY KEY of the parent table 
>      consists of a a different number of columns to the child key in 
>      the child table.
>
> then … a "foreign key mismatch" error [is raised].

```
> DELETE FROM Child;
Error: foreign key mismatch
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX di ON Department(DepartmentId);
> DELETE FROM Child;
>
```

Comment: yes, I agree with you 100 %, I designed the SQL in ErWin/ErX. Fact remains though, that both the tables parent and child are empty when I issued this command.

Comment: SQLite checks the table structure before actually trying to delete records.

Comment: OMG, I didn't see that one coming. I had a unique constraint on (departmentId, departmentCode) in table Department, but no single unique index on departmentId, which is needed. Many thanks. I reckon I will run into this a few more times. Now I know what to look for. Many thanks!